# django create instant messaging

Tags: django, chat

I'm building a django website and would like a to add an instant messaging feature to my userbase. What are some good ways to go about implementing this functionality? Does Channels and websockets have anything to do with this? Scratch that... so I'm looking at Django channels and it looks like a way to build a chat feature. Do many people just build theirs from the ground up or do they use an existing app?

I'm looking for more of a user-user chat as opposed to user to chatroom.  I've looked around a bit, but there are many answers from 7-8 years ago. I'd appreciate some guidance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does Channels and websockets have anything to do with this?

You should definitely use WebSocket for your chat app and Django channels are a way to build a chat feature since Channels project takes Django and extends its abilities beyond HTTP - to handle WebSockets, chat protocols, IoT protocols, and more.

You can take a look at this example: [djangochat](https://www.ploggingdev.com/2017/11/building-a-chat-room-using-django-channels/)